# Using R to removing duplicate rows from a data frame based on certain conditions

Tags: r

I'm working on a project where I need to sort data based on how people vote. I cannot find a function where I can delete duplicate rows based on certain conditions being met.

I'm looking for a function that will remove duplicate rows based on one column having duplicate values and another column meeting certain conditions.

For example in the table below I would like to remove voters who voted in three different elections. Paul needs to be removed from this data frame.

```
 df <- data.frame(Name=c("Paul","Paul","Mary","Bill","Jane","Paul","Mary","John",
"Bill","John"),ElectionDay=c("November 2010","November 2014",
"November 2010","November 2010","November 2014","November 2006",
"November 2014","November 2010","November 2014","November 2014"))

df
#    Name   ElectionDay
# 1  Paul November 2010
# 2  Paul November 2014
# 3  Mary November 2010
# 4  Bill November 2010
# 5  Jane November 2014
# 6  Paul November 2006
# 7  Mary November 2014
# 8  John November 2010
# 9  Bill November 2014
# 10 John November 2014
```

Below is an example of the result I am looking for:

```
   Name   ElectionDay
1  Mary November 2010
2  Bill November 2010
3  Jane November 2014
4  Mary November 2014
5  John November 2010
6  Bill November 2014
7  John November 2014
```

Answer (score 6):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Name', we get the length of unique 'ElectionDay' (`uniqueN(ElectionDay)`).  If the length is less than 3, we get the Subset of Data.Table (`.SD`).

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df)[, if(uniqueN(ElectionDay) < 3) .SD, by = Name]
```

---

A similar base R option would be using `ave`.  We get the `length` of `unique` elements of 'ElectionDay' grouped by 'Name' and check whether it is less than 3 to get a logical index.  The index can be used to subset the rows of dataset.

```
df[with(df, ave(as.character(ElectionDay), Name,
                FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))) < 3,]
#   Name   ElectionDay
#3  Mary November 2010
#4  Bill November 2010
#5  Jane November 2014
#7  Mary November 2014
#8  John November 2010
#9  Bill November 2014
#10 John November 2014
```

Answer (score 4):

The names that occur in more than 2 rows are calculated as

```
names(which(table(df$Name) > 2))
#[1] "Paul"
```

So what you need is

```
df[!(df$Name %in% names(which(table(df$Name) > 2))), ]
#   Name   ElectionDay
#3  Mary November 2010
#4  Bill November 2010
#5  Jane November 2014
#7  Mary November 2014
#8  John November 2010
#9  Bill November 2014
#10 John November 2014
```

Comment: Or `df[df$Name %in% names(which(table(df$Name)<3)),]`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also use dplyr, counting the number of elections on which every people voted and then removing the rows for which the count is 3:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(NumberElections = length(unique(ElectionDay))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(NumberElections != 3)
```

Comment: You could make it compact with `df %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(n_distinct(ElectionDay)<3)`